# Can I ask what solutions exist for design problems of a physical product?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question about how light from an LED can be (and is often) diffused evenly across a surface, for example, as in back-lit LCD displays, or lit-up (shaped) panels of electrical appliances and so on. I want to know what materials, structures and design techniques (or generally, what solutions) are used to solve these kinds of problems. Would this be an acceptable question for physics.stackexchange.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My view is **no**, as this is more of an engineering question than a physics question.

Now, if you found out that material X somehow diffused the light and you wanted to ask *why* material X diffused the light, that would be on topic.

Comment: Yep, I fully agree with this.